# 配列にdupまたはdeep_dupでコピーしてもコピーした対象が変化してしまう現象を解決したい

Tags: ruby

Rubyで信号処理をしています．
その際に，あるクラス内に以下のようなコードの部分があります．

```
txs = @_transmits.dup # or deep_dup: require 'active_support'
rxs = @_receives.dup  # or deep_dup

dist = makeNonlinearSignal(txs) # クラス内メソッド
```

この部分において，メソッド`makeNonlinearSignal`前後で`txs`の中身が変化してしまいます．
ちなみに`makeNonlinearSignal`メソッドの中身は以下です．

```
# PAの歪み信号とLNAの歪み信号を返す
def makeNonlinearSignal(signal)
  distPA = channelTimeDomainConvolution(signal.map! {|a| a * a.abs2})
  distLNA = channelTimeDomainConvolution(signal.map! {|a| a + @_paCoef * a * a.abs2}).map {|a| a * a.abs2}

  return distPA, distLNA
end
```

Rubyは引数による変数の渡しはでき，受けができないはずなのですが，この原因がわかりません．
さらに，`dup`（少し浅い）及び`deep_dup`（深い）でコピーしてもどちらもメソッド後に信号が変化してしまいます．

どのようにしたら`txs`は変化しないようにできますでしょうか．
ご教授お願いいたします．

Comment: 先程投稿して思いましたが，`makeNonlinearSignal`メソッド内で`map!`をして`signal`自体を置換してしまっているからでしょうか？`map`であれば変化しないのでしょうか．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!`の破壊的メソッドを使用していたため，`makeNolinearSignal`メソッドの引数`signal`にそのまま`map`されることが原因と判明しました.